# Slow startup of next activity after closing interstitial ad (AdMob)?

Tags: java, android, admob

When I upgraded from the old Google AdMob SDK to the new Google Pay Services SDK, I noticed a difference in how quickly the interstitial ad closes and starts the next activity (which also brings up a new layout). In the past, it was near instant. Now, with the new Play Services interstitial, I have noticed a 1-2 second delay after clicking "x" on the interstitial before the new activity starts.

How can I get rid of this delay?

```
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    final Intent nextActive = new Intent("activity");

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);


    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            //Intent nextActive = new Intent("activity");
            startActivity(nextActive);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            //Intent nextActive = new Intent("activity");
            startActivity(nextActive);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayInterstitial();
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you provide some code? especially how and when do you start the next activity?

Comment: @Michael added a snippet

Comment: Have you tried to start the activity on adLoaded/onAdFailedToLoad? I am not a 100% sure, but if you try it like this, the activity should be ready after the user closes the interstitial! (not tried it myself though)

Comment: I have noticed the same. onAdClosed is called with a small delay, even in 2021.